# What's these symbols style name/source?

Tags: schematics, diagram, symbol

I've found a lot of schematic diagrams that use this style of symbols, specially in the Wikipedia. I think these symbols are pretty clear and stylish. I would love to use them for the schematics I make but I've found just a few in the format I want (SVG). They are auploaded by diferent users so I think they are getting those from different sources.

[image]

I make schematics containing mostly MOSFET and BJT transistors and there are not much of those symbols in this style.
Does this kind of symbols (blue/grayish shading, solid component lines, thin wire lines, etc) have a name? and where to find more?

Comment: You can create your own library in MS Word, and save it as ClipArt. In any case you have to follow some rules in schematics, like IEEE's.

Comment: I prefer to use scalable-vector graphics software like Inkscape.

Comment: Schematics symmbols created in MS Word are scalable and you can flip or rotate.

Comment: Be careful about that shaded diode symbol; if the diode was connected backwards and the wires crossed behind the diode symbol, it would not be obvious because of the filled symbol. This was a problem for us on PADS a couple of years ago; switching to an unfilled symbol revealed the schematic capture error.  Of course that's only relevant if you're making a real CAD schematic with a netlist etc. Shaded symbols suggest it's only a picture of a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digikey's "Scheme-it" software looks similar. You can try it for free at http://www.digikey.com/schemeit.

That's the closest I could find, but as the others said you can create schematics in this style very easily with any drawing program. MS Paint is a very common one, and gives you the freedom to draw any component the way you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the internal shading (which I don't like), those are common schematic symbols which could come from any electronic CAD program.